# How to manage local PHP common files?

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-yosemite, finder

I googled many times for a best practice tip to manage my PHP common files on a local development environment but I never found something that worked out for me, so finally I managed to ask here.

This is my scenario: I'm a PHP developer working on a local MAMP environment, and I would like to manage my scripts from one source folder. This is **not** what I'm looking for:

- GIT
- PHP require files from within another folder but the one the software would expect to find them once in production

I'm looking for something as easy as a symlink (which actually doesn't seem to work…) or a solution to keep files sync across folders (i.e. everytime i save **/DEV/SCRIPTS/SCRIPT_1/script.php** every "copy" of this file is overwritten with the latest one, let's say **/DEV/PROJECT_1/SCRIPTS/script.php** etc.)

how do you manage this?

thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of the common files you are talking about?

Comment: would something like a 'file synchronization' utility do what you want? i.e. [projects/freefilesync/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/). Is just a guess. And maybe 'over the top'.

Comment: yep, file sync could be a way to achieve this… what I need is that if I need to (re)use a Wordpress Plugin or a PHP Class or a Zend Module across many projects, all I have to do is "link" somehow the same folder or file from my main DEV source folder and once i change THAT file, all other inclusions get updated too…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to you **rsync**, with this application you can sync any kind of files anywhere. It can sync local and remote files.

```
[root@tecmint]$ rsync -avz rpmpkgs/ root@192.168.0.101:/home/

root@192.168.0.101's password:

sending incremental file list

./

httpd-2.2.3-82.el5.centos.i386.rpm

mod_ssl-2.2.3-82.el5.centos.i386.rpm

nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz

nagios-plugins-1.4.16.tar.gz

sent 4993369 bytes  received 91 bytes  399476.80 bytes/sec
```

You can find detailed information about rsync here: http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/

Comment: this could work, maybe an interface would help to track destination folders and push updates… ty diego!